# How to add two UIView with collection view inside to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ui view

```
class StoriesView : UIView {
   //collection view inside
}

class NewsFeedView : UIView {
//collection view inside
}
```

In my UIViewController I want to add these views

```
class HomeViewController : UIViewController {
 private var _newsFeedView : NewsFeedView{return view as! NewsFeedView}
    private var _storiesView : StoriesView{return view as! StoriesView}
//
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = NewsFeedView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        view = StoriesView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        _newsFeedView.collectionView.delegate = self
        _newsFeedView.collectionView.dataSource = self

        _storiesView.storiesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        _storiesView.storiesCollectionView.delegate = self

    }

}
```

and I'm getting error saying 
Could not cast value of type 'Vidyoga.StoriesView' (0x104db7338) to 'Vidyoga.NewsFeedView' (0x104db7050)

Comment: You are assigning `view` twice: `view = NewsFeedView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)` and then `view = StoriesView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`. Make two properties instead.

Comment: Are you creating your UI programmatically or are you using Interface Builder/Storyboards?

Comment: @koen how to create two properties ?? sorry I'm new to these things

Comment: @AdamPro13 I'm creating UI programmatically

Comment: @AashishBogati You can only have one `view` per screen. Maybe you can explain more what exactly you want to accomplish. Please read [ask] for suggestions how to improve your question.

Comment: @koen I want to add two collection view in one view controllers that's all but I want to create collection view in different files using UIVIew

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you want, it's still confusing.

Comment: @koen same as instagram app where stories collection view and after that newsfeeds collection view

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use instagram. Please add a picture.

Comment: @koen https://c7.uihere.com/files/202/111/798/iphone-with-mobile-ui-kit-instagram-smartphone-mockup-and-chat-app.jpg here the image I want to create sth like this

Comment: @AashishBogati what is the NewsFeedView and StoriesView in that picture? Are you  talking about the big circles, or the icons at the bottom?

Comment: StoriesView is the circular one and newsfeedView is large rectangular view

Comment: @AashishBogati You wrote earlier "sorry I'm new to these things" - so maybe you should start with a simple app to learn the basics before starting on a more complicated project.

Comment: @koen thanks for the advice and thanks for your help as well I managed to solve the problem I added two UIView as subviews of HomeViewController and add anchor to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This is how I did it 

        private var _newsFeedView = NewsFeedView()
        private var _storiesView = StoriesView()
    //
        //MARK:- LIFECYCLE

        override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
            view.addSubview(_storiesView)
            view.addSubview(_newsFeedView)

            _storiesView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor,padding: .init(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),size: .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 100))
            //
            _newsFeedView.anchor(top: _storiesView.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor,padding: .init(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),size: .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 0))

            _newsFeedView.collectionView.delegate = self
            _newsFeedView.collectionView.dataSource = self

            _storiesView.storiesCollectionView.dataSource = self
            _storiesView.storiesCollectionView.delegate = self

        }
```